# Folland's real analysis, 2.49 theorem: $\Phi^{-1}$ commutes complement?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm having difficulty in following Folland's theorem 2.49, where he states

> We denote $S^{n-1}$ as the unit sphere $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|x|=1\}$. If $x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$, the polar coordinates of $x$ are
> $$r=|x| \in (0,\infty)$$
> $$x'=x/|x| \in S^{n-1}$$
> The map $\Phi(x)=(r,x')$ is a continuous bijection from $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ to $(0,\infty)\times S^{n-1}$ whose continuous inverse is $\Phi^{-1}(r,x')=rx'$. We denote by $m_*$ the Borel measure on $(0,\infty)\times S^{n-1}$ induced by $\Phi$ from Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is, $m_*(E)=m(\Phi^{-1}(E))$. We define the measure $\rho=\rho_n$ on $(0,\infty)$ by $\rho(E) = \int_E r^{n-1} dr$.
>
> **2.49 Theorem**
> There is a unique Borel measure $\sigma= \sigma_{n-1}$ on $S^{n-1}$ such that $m_*= \rho \times \sigma$. If $f$ is Borel measurable on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f \ge 0 $ or $f \in L^1(m)$, then
> $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) \,dx = \int_0^\infty \int_{S^{n-1}} f(rx') r^{n-1} d \, \sigma (x') dr. $$

In its proof, the author says

[image]

As circled in red, I don't understand why the map $\Phi^{-1}:E \to E_1$ commutes complements. We want to show $\Phi^{-1}((0,a]\times E^c) = \{rx':0<r\leq a, x'\in E^c\} = \{rx': 0<r\leq a, x'\in E\}^c$, right?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a duplicate.  See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2747927/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4728062/ .

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks! I think they are asking about the same theorem but are different questions. This is asking about the property of $\Phi^{-1}$'s complement commutation and the ones you refer to asked about the special case of $f$ as a characteristic function and a Lebesgue measurable function.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text to convey information that is not otherwise present in your post. [See here for an explanation of why this is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: I think the map $E\mapsto E_1$ is not $\Phi^{-1}.$ $E$ is a subset of $S^{n-1}$ and $E_1=\Phi((0,1)\times E).$ And if you agree that this map commutes with union and intersections, you are left with little to check for it to commute also with complements.

Comment: @AnneBauval If the whole set is $\{rx': 0<r\leq a\}$, then I can see this map commutes with complements. I'm not sure whether the requirement "$0<r\leq a$" stays

Comment: I do not understand your last comment. Did you understand mine?

Comment: @AnneBauval I think $E_1$ is not $\Phi((0,1)\times E)$, but $\Phi^{-1}((0,1)\times E)$, as underlined in blue in the question text. For complement commutation, I honestly do not understand well why it commutes complements, sorry...

Comment: You are right I confused $\Phi$ with its inverse. Now this map $\Psi:P(S^{n-1})\to P(B),\;E\mapsto E_1=\Phi^{-1}((0,1)\times E)$ (where $B$ is the open unit ball, minus its center), commutes with union and intersection hence also with complement: if $F=E^c$ in $S^{n-1}$ then $\Psi(F)=\Psi(E)^c$ in $B$ since $\Psi(F)\cap\Psi(E)=\Psi(F\cap E)=\Psi(\varnothing)=\varnothing$ and similarly, $\Psi(F)\cup\Psi(E)=\dots=B.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks a lot!